# How to get a disparity map from depth map in Blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, depth-map, stereoscopy

I am trying to convert the depth map to a disparity map but I got some problems. Here is my setting in compositing nodes.

[image]

I use these two equations:
(1) focal_length(pixel) = focal_length(mm) * resolution_x(pixel) / sensor_size_width(mm)
(2) disparity = baseline(m) * focal_length(pixel) / depth(m)

The result is weird, as you can see. The output(disparity map) is totally bright. What's more, I can't use it to train my stereo match network, something must be wrong. Could anyone tell me how to fix it? Thanks.

One more question, in order to train my network, I have to convert disparity map files(.exr) to .pfm format. What tools can I use to complete this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My setup follows the same formulas you described:

[image: Disparity nodes]

This should be enough if you want to save your disparity to file (possibly in OpenEXR format since it is the only format able to handle floating point values).
If you want to render it as well, you should add some visualization nodes:
In particular you should divide the disparity (which in the previous image would be the output of the last divide node) by the width of the image (or more in general for your disparity range, if you have a minimum disparity value before dividing you should also subtract it from the disparity).

One more suggestion to make your life easier: instead of hardcoding the camera / stereo rig parameters directly in the value nodes, you should add the values using drivers. I'll show you an example with the stereo rig's baseline:

[image: Driver1]

[image: Driver2]

Add a value node:

[image: Driver3]

Paste the copied driver on the value node:

[image: Driver4]

EDIT:
I forgot to answer the last question about the conversion from .exr to .pfm:
I think the quickest way to achieve this is to do it in Python: open the .exr file using OpenCV in the following way:

```
os.environ["OPENCV_IO_ENABLE_OPENEXR"] = "1"
import cv2

...

img = cv2.imread("filename.exr",  cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

and either save it in .pfm using OpenCV:

```
cv2.imwrite("filename.pfm", img)
```

or do so by using a script belonging to one of the many disparity estimation deep learning's repositories you can find on GitHub (you can find some of those here: https://www.programcreek.com/python/?CodeExample=write+pfm)